# AS2: Mouse moves too fast messes up function

Tags: flash, function, actionscript, actionscript-2, mousemove

I am using the following code as part of a set of scrollable bars to change each bar in relation to another when one is dragged. It works until the user swipes the bar as fast as possible then the numbers go wrong... I'm sure this is the function unable to process as fast as the mouse but anyone know a way around this?

```
onClipEvent (load) {
    Symptoms_sliders = new Array(this._parent.slider1.slider, this._parent.slider2.slider, this._parent.slider3.slider, this._parent.slider4.slider, this._parent.slider5.slider);
    Food_sliders = new Array(this._parent.slider6.slider, this._parent.slider7.slider, this._parent.slider8.slider, this._parent.slider9.slider);
    for (i=0; i<Food_sliders.length; i++) {
        Food_sliders[i]._y = 75;
    }
    is_scrolling = 0;
    function Food_scroll_ratio() {
        init_scroll_diff = init_scroll_num-init_scroll._y;
        Slider_ratio = new Array();
        totalLeft = init_scroll_num;
        while (_global.init_moved != init_scroll._y) {
            for (i=0; i<Food_sliders.length; i++) {
                if (Food_sliders[i] != init_scroll) {
                    slider_pos = Food_sliders[i]._y;
                    percentageOf = ((100-init_slider_pos[i])/totalLeft)*100;
                    percentageMultiplier = 100/percentageOf;
                    trace(percentageMultiplier);
                    if (init_scroll_num == 0) {
                        scroll_change = Math.round(Math.abs(init_scroll_diff/3));
                    } else {
                        scroll_change = Math.round(Math.abs(init_scroll_diff)/percentageMultiplier);
                    }
                    if (percentageOf == Infinity) {
                        Food_sliders[i]._y = 100;
                    } else if (init_scroll_diff>0) {
                        Food_sliders[i]._y = init_slider_pos[i]+scroll_change;
                    } else if (init_scroll_diff<0) {
                        Food_sliders[i]._y = init_slider_pos[i]-scroll_change;
                    }

                }
            }
            _global.init_moved = init_scroll._y;

        }
    }
}
onClipEvent (mouseMove) {
    for (i=0; i<Food_sliders.length; i++) {
        Food_sliders[i].onPress = function() {
            startDrag(this, false, 0, 100, 0, 0);
            init_scroll_num = this._y;
            init_scroll = this;
            is_scrolling = 1;
            init_slider_pos = new Array();
            init_slider_pos.push(Food_sliders[0]._y);
            init_slider_pos.push(Food_sliders[1]._y);
            init_slider_pos.push(Food_sliders[2]._y);
            init_slider_pos.push(Food_sliders[3]._y);
        };
        Food_sliders[i].onRelease = Food_sliders[i].onReleaseOutside=function () {
            stopDrag();
            is_scrolling = 0;
        };
    }
    if (is_scrolling == 1) {
        Food_scroll_ratio();
    }
}
```

Comment: mouseMove is dispatched a lot more than enterFrame, so try that. Also, you don't need to initialize arrays and assign listeners every time the mouse moves, you setup once, and update on mouseMove/enterFrame

Comment: it is on mouseMove =/, I do need to set up those arrays because they must be clear the next time it is clicked/moved as they must update each time.

Comment: I'm suggesting you should try onClipEvent(enterFrame) instead of onClipEvent (mouseMove) and see if that's slightly better. All the this._parent.slider6.slider and alike references look like repeat code. This can be written in a clearer/cleaner manner. Try to keep it [dry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself). Can you describe simply what are you trying to achieve ? I don't understand how your sliders should work.

Comment: Enterframe is slower and I need to run this function only on mouse move, those are arrays of the sliders. This function works that isn't the problem it's that if you move the mouse to quick it can't keep up and I'm looking for ways to safety net it. (In a nutshell the sliders must all equal 100% - this function makes them decrease and increase at a rate depending on their original values. So say they one is at 30% another 20% another 10% and another 40%. If you drag the 40% one up the others must change but the largest changes the most and the smallest the least).

Comment: I'm guessing initializing arrays and looping so often can slow things down. When the user drags the current slider, it updates the rest of the sliders also, using the value of the current slider divided a ratio determined by the 'distance' of others to the dragged one (closer sliders are affected more than the ones further) - somewhat similar to how an osx dock scales up and down, right ?

Comment: Pretty much, cant quite remember the scaling of an OSx dock but the sliders actually move based upon their distance from 100% the higher the percentage the greater the move so that your slider on 90% may drop to 83% before the one on 2% drops to 1%. You are probably right about the arrays but I use them to match one set of data with another because all my index numbers are consistent across them, can't see this function running without them.

Comment: I've done a [quick demo](http://lifesine.eu/so/sliderRatio.swf) in actionscript 3 using the default Slider component in Flash. The [code](http://pastebin.com/EQjEWbg2) snippet is also available. The idea is you can either use the physical distance(x,y) between the sliders or their id to determine the 'distance' between the rest of the sliders in relation to the one controlled by user. You use that distance to divide/scale down the value of the currently active slider. I would suggest writing a nice tidy slider component or googling for something nice and clean 1st then returning to your issue.

Comment: Interesting, but alas I must use AS2 due to our userbases flash version. Also while the scroller works on the same basis, it doesn't work to the same end, the scrollers in mine must always = 100% at any given time and it is their relative sizes that then determine the ratio at which they move to make up for the sliding of one of them. I wrote a function which determines the difference between 100 and the sliders total, finds the biggest % slider and adds or subtracts accordingly, it runs 20ms after the mouse stops moving after any slider is slid and does the job... ill post it in answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem still occurs and I don't think it can be avoided but I use another function  (`Slider_checker`) that runs once 20ms after the mouse is idle everytime the mouse scrolls a scrollbar (the 20ms allows it to ensure that all loops of Food_Scroll_ratio are finished so nothing interferes with it and saves some cpu cycles).

Here is my final code:

```
onClipEvent (load) {
    Symptoms_sliders = new Array(this._parent.slider1.slider, this._parent.slider2.slider, this._parent.slider3.slider, this._parent.slider4.slider, this._parent.slider5.slider);
    Food_sliders = new Array(this._parent.slider6.slider, this._parent.slider7.slider, this._parent.slider8.slider, this._parent.slider9.slider);
    for (i=0; i<Food_sliders.length; i++) {
        Food_sliders[i]._y = 75;
    }
    is_scrolling = 0;
    Slider_check_interval = 0;
    var mouseTimerID:Number;
    var delay:Number = 50;
    var mouseMoveListener = new Object();
    mouseMoveListener.onMouseMove = function() {
        clearInterval(mouseTimerID);
        mouseTimerID = setInterval(Slider_checker, delay);
    };
    Slider_checker = function () {
        while (Slider_check_interval == 1) {
            count = 0;
            for (i=0; i<Food_sliders.length; i++) {
                count += 100-Food_sliders[i]._y;
            }
            if (count != 100 && count != 0) {
                mxm = Food_sliders[0];
                for (i=0; i<Food_sliders.length; i++) {
                    if (Food_sliders[i]._y<mxm._y) {
                        mxm = Food_sliders[i];
                    }
                }
                if (count>100) {
                    mxm._y += count-100;
                }
                if (count<100) {
                    mxm._y -= 100-count;
                }
            }
            Slider_check_interval = 0;
        }
    };


    Mouse.addListener(mouseMoveListener);
    function Food_scroll_ratio() {
        init_scroll_diff = init_scroll_num-init_scroll._y;
        totalLeft = init_scroll_num;
        Slider_check = new Array();
        for (i=0; i<Food_sliders.length; i++) {
            if (Food_sliders[i] != init_scroll) {
                slider_pos = Food_sliders[i]._y;
                percentageOf = ((100-init_slider_pos[i])/totalLeft)*100;
                percentageMultiplier = 100/percentageOf;
                if (init_scroll_num == 0) {
                    scroll_change = Math.round(Math.abs(init_scroll_diff/3));
                } else {
                    scroll_change = Math.round(Math.abs(init_scroll_diff)/percentageMultiplier);
                }
                if (percentageOf == Infinity) {
                    Food_sliders[i]._y = 100;
                } else if (init_scroll_diff>0) {
                    Food_sliders[i]._y = init_slider_pos[i]+scroll_change;
                } else if (init_scroll_diff<0) {
                    Food_sliders[i]._y = init_slider_pos[i]-scroll_change;
                }
            }
        }
        Slider_check_interval = 1;
    }
}
onClipEvent (mouseMove) {
    for (i=0; i<Food_sliders.length; i++) {
        Food_sliders[i].onPress = function() {
            startDrag(this, false, 0, 100, 0, 0);
            init_scroll_num = this._y;
            init_scroll = this;
            is_scrolling = 1;
            init_slider_pos = new Array();
            init_slider_pos.push(Food_sliders[0]._y);
            init_slider_pos.push(Food_sliders[1]._y);
            init_slider_pos.push(Food_sliders[2]._y);
            init_slider_pos.push(Food_sliders[3]._y);
        };
        Food_sliders[i].onRelease = Food_sliders[i].onReleaseOutside=function () {
            stopDrag();
            is_scrolling = 0;
        };

    }
    if (is_scrolling == 1) {
        Food_scroll_ratio();
    }
}
```